# Router: No routes matched location "/" error react-router-dom v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I recently migrated from `react-router-dom V5 to v6` and I got the following message below:

`index.js:44 No routes matched location "/"`

Here is how my App component looks

```
const joinedSignupRoutes = `/(${allSteps
  .map((step) => step.path.substr(1))
  .join('|')})`;

const App = ({ history }) => {
  return (
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path={joinedSignupRoutes} element={<RegistrationRoutes />} />
```

Any thoughts on how to solve this will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add a route for path `"/"` since it's missing.

Example:

```
const joinedSignupRoutes = `/(${allSteps
  .map((step) => step.path.substr(1))
  .join('|')})`;

const App = ({ history }) => {
  return (
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<h1>Home</h1>} /> // <-- replace with actual component
        <Route path={joinedSignupRoutes} element={<RegistrationRoutes />} />
      </Routes>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  );
};
```

### Update

> ... instead of having `<Route path="/" element={<h1>Home</h1>} />` as
> the landing page I want to have the `<Route path={joinedSignupRoutes} element={<RegistrationRoutes />} />`. That is the first page to be
> viewed when the App runs should be the RegistrationRoutes component.

You still need to render a route on path `"/"` to maintain an invariant that `react-router-dom@6` enforces, but you can render anything on this route. In this case you can render a redirect to your `joinedSignupRoutes` route.

Example:

```
import { ...., Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const joinedSignupRoutes = `/(${allSteps
  .map((step) => step.path.substr(1))
  .join('|')})`;

const App = ({ history }) => {
  return (
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={<Navigate to={joinedSignupRoutes} replace />} 
        />
        <Route path={joinedSignupRoutes} element={<RegistrationRoutes />} />
      </Routes>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  );
};
```

### Update 2

> ```
> // Joins all signup paths to a singel route to multimatch it against.
> // eg. path="/(step-1|step-2|step-3)"
> const joinedSignupRoutes = `/(${allSteps
>   .map((step) => step.path.substr(1))
>   .join("|")})`;
> ```

`react-router-dom@5` routes could take `path` props that used regular expressions. This is not the case in `react-router-dom@6`.

See [What Happened to Regexp Routes paths?](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/faq#what-happened-to-regexp-routes-paths)

> Regexp route paths were removed for two reasons:
>
> 1. Regular expression paths in routes raised a lot of questions for v6's ranked route matching. How do you rank a regex?
> 2. We were able to shed an entire dependency (path-to-regexp) and cut the package weight sent to your user's browser significantly. If it
>    were added back, it would represent 1/3 of React Router's page weight!
>
> After looking at a lot of use cases, we found we can still meet them
> without direct regexp path support, so we made the tradeoff to
> significantly decrease the bundle size and avoid the open questions
> around ranking regexp routes.
>
> The majority of regexp routes were only concerned about one URL
> segment at a time and doing one of two things:
>
> 1. Matching multiple static values
> 2. Validating the param in some way (is a number, not a number, etc.)

To handle this in v6 you will need an explicit route for each path. Redirect from `"/"` to `"/step-1"`

Example:

```
import { ...., Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const joinedSignupRoutes = `/(${allSteps
  .map((step) => step.path.substr(1))
  .join('|')})`;

const App = ({ history }) => {
  return (
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={<Navigate to={allSteps[0]} replace />} 
        />
        {allSteps.map(path => (
          <Route
            key={path}
            path={path}
            element={<RegistrationRoutes />}
          />
        ))}
      </Routes>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  );
};
```

Comment: I actually want to make the "joinedSignupRoutes"/RegistrationRoutes have the parent or home component

Comment: @EfosaAlohan Sorry, I don't understand what that means. Can you clarify?

Comment: What I mean is that instead of having <Route path="/" element={<h1>Home</h1>} as the landing page I want to have the <Route path={joinedSignupRoutes} element={<RegistrationRoutes />} />. That is the first page to be viewed when the App runs should be the RegistrationRoutes component.

Comment: @EfosaAlohan I see. You can render a redirect on `"/"` then. I'll update my answer.

Comment: This was not an issue with react-router-dom v5 until I migrated to V6

Comment: Thanks looking forward to the updated answer!

Comment: @EfosaAlohan Ok, please check update.

Comment: No luck all I got was all paths in the {joinedSignupRoutes} in the browser without rendering any component.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244098/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-efosa-alohan).

Comment: @EfosaAlohan Were you able to create an updated running codesandbox?

Comment: @DrewResse the major issue is with connected-react-router not compatible with react-router-dom V6.

Comment: @EfosaAlohan Oof ‍♂️ and I totally knew that and blew it. I was focused on the route matching issue you'd asked about. Yeah, `connected-react-router` has yet to update to support RRDv6. Sorry. If you are trying to use a redux connected router you'll need to stick to RRDv4/5, or fork the repo and dig in and fix things yourself. I know a few issues have been filed but unfortunately that repo doesn't seem to have a lot of active development ATM.

Comment: I came across redux-first-redux on this page https://github.com/salvoravida/redux-first-history. Have you heard of it before? I will give it a try by next week.

Comment: @EfosaAlohan I had heard of `redux-first-history` a while back as a promising workaround when RRDv6 first released.